# Input 0 of layer lstm_11 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 5000, 1, 6]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I am developing a bitcoin price predictor using Keras. I got data from [binance.com](http://binance.com). Data structure is like this which is for 5,000 hours:

> [
> ['1597773600000' '11983.22000000' '12010.95000000' '11948.40000000' '11978.18000000' '2344.24787500']
> ['1597777200000' '11978.19000000' '12029.00000000' '11964.63000000' '11982.00000000' '1993.81400900']
> ['1597780800000' '11981.99000000' '12037.86000000' '11978.07000000' '12022.99000000' '2092.06777400']
> ...
> ['1586962800000' '6717.66000000' '6745.51000000' '6690.00000000' '6701.90000000' '3279.59274200']
> ['1586966400000' '6701.90000000' '6749.69000000' '6690.00000000' '6729.58000000' '2511.60203300']
> ['1586970000000' '6729.59000000' '6763.13000000' '6724.51000000' '6746.86000000' '1660.33553000']
> ]
>
> Shape=  (5000, 6)
> Size=  30000
> ndim=  2

In every entry, first element is timestamp. I need to reshape it to (samples, timestamp, features). I did it like this:

```
btcData = np.reshape(btcData,(5000, 1, 6))
```

Then I normalized data and built model. Model is here:

```
myModel = keras.Sequential(name='cryptoPredictor')
myModel.add(keras.Input(np.shape(train_data),))
myModel.summary()
myModel.add(LSTM(128, activation='tanh'))
myModel.summary()
myModel.add(LSTM(128, activation='tanh'))
myModel.summary()
myModel.add(Dense(1))
myModel.summary()
myModel.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
myModel.fit(train_data, test_data, batch_size=100, epochs=50, validation_split=15.0)
```

When I run the model, I receive this error:

> Input 0 of layer lstm_11 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape
> received: [None, 5000, 1, 6]

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: where's the label? why are there 6 values per element? are these the previous values? is this a windowed dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have 5,000 rows with 1 time step and 6 features, you have to change this:

1. Set the input shape to `(1, 6)`
2. Set `return_sequences=True` for the second layer

Then it works:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(5000, 1, 6)
y = np.random.rand(5000)

myModel = keras.Sequential(name='cryptoPredictor')
myModel.add(keras.Input(shape=np.shape(X)[1:]))
myModel.summary()
myModel.add(LSTM(8, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
myModel.summary()
myModel.add(LSTM(8, activation='tanh'))
myModel.summary()
myModel.add(Dense(1))
myModel.summary()
myModel.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
history = myModel.fit(X, y, batch_size=8, epochs=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to reshape your data into a shape as `(5000,6)` as the first dimension needed by the lstm is the batch_size, then timestep, then sample.
Feature and batch size can be seen as synonym here:

```
btcData = np.reshape(btcData,(5000,6))
```

Comment: This is new error after implementing your solution:  'Input 0 of layer lstm_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 128]'

Comment: yes because you are putting an LSTM behind an LSTM. for that you need to set `return_sequences=True` at the first LSTM layer. I absolutely recommend you to start with one LSTM first, it seems like you are trying too much at once